# Report on individual password expiration intervals in Sybase ASE 12.5

Tags: sap-ase, database-security

I want to run a report to make sure the password of every user is set to expire every 30 days, but the expiration interval doesn't seem to be stored in syslogins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get report with following proc:

```
use sybsystemprocs
go
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
print 'sp__helpexpire'
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if exists (select 1 from sysobjects where  type = "P" and  name = "sp__helpexpire")
        drop proc sp__helpexpire
go
create procedure sp__helpexpire
as
begin
  set nocount on
  declare @swexpire int
  select @swexpire=value from master.dbo.sysconfigures
    where name = 'systemwide password expiration'
  print "Serverwide password expire: %1!" ,@swexpire
  print ""
  print "Logins:"
  print "=============================================================="
  select l.name login , case a.int_value
      when null then @swexpire
      else a.int_value end "expire in days"
    from master.dbo.syslogins l , master.dbo.sysattributes a
    where l.suid *= a.object
      and a.object_type='PS'
      and a.attribute=0
      and object_cinfo='login'
  print ""
  print "Roles:"
  print "=============================================================="
  select r.name "role name", case a.int_value
      when null then @swexpire
      else a.int_value end "expire in days"
    from master.dbo.syssrvroles r , master.dbo.sysattributes a
    where r.srid *= a.object
      and a.object_type='PS'
      and a.attribute=0
      and object_cinfo='role'
end
go
```

it is always a good idea to check source code of those system procedures (stored in sybsystemprocs database) which manipulate with records you are looking for (in this case it is sp_addlogin, sp_modifylogin)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sp_configure to set all users password expiration date

```
sp_configure "systemwide password expiration", 30
go
```

will set all users passwords to expire after 30 days. Not sure if this value can be read for a report though. The default is 0.

Answer (score 0):

try

exec sp_displaylogin

to get the perms for the settings for an individual user, logged in as that user.